# Locations updating only after saving a second time

Tags: location, google-maps

Primary tabs
View(active tab)
Edit
Posted by P013370 on January 3, 2014 at 6:14pm
I updated the majority of my node's locations using feeds module. Everything was mapped and updated correctly. However, I have noticed that when I use proximity search many results do not appear. They only appear after I go into the affected nodes and re-update their location a bit, then save. For example, a node with a zipcode of 02108 was not appearing under proximity search. After removing the zip code and saving it appeared. I even added the zip code back again, and the node appeared under the proximity search. I have over 3,000 nodes and cannot repeat this process indefinitely. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the location/gps data being save the first time the node is saved?

Comment: Yes. I am importing data via feeds module and feeds location module. When I open the affected nodes, the data appears in the correct fields. However, one thing I noticed is that any node manually created works perfectly from the start.

Comment: hmm...are you sure the affected nodes are published?

Comment: Yes, all nodes appear on a page view. However, When I filter by proximity they do not appear when they shoudl.

Comment: Each time I update a node's location, I get an error like this in the logs: `Conserving lid 1234 due to uniqueness`. I know that a similar issue has been addressed at https://drupal.org/node/851310, but this issue seems to involve node location and location cck both being enabled. I do not have node location enabled, and am only using location cck.